# Can't resolve '@babel/helper-module-imports' with Font Awesome

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

So, this may well be a lack of understanding on my part. I am experiencing an error (See below), when I leave this line in.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { solid } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro' <<<<===== THIS LINE IS CAUSING ERROR BELOW
```

The error is: -

> ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/helper-module-imports' in
> 'C:\Dropbox\Trusted\Modern React BootCamp\12. Exercise -
> Yahtzee\node_modules@fortawesome\fontawesome-svg-core'

Within the package.json I have this installed: -

```
{
  "name": "yahtzee",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5"
  }
}
```

It was just trying to get this line to work.

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid('user-secret')} />
```

So, I could rework this piece of code in React (My react is a work in progress, if I was being generous).

```
  <FontAwesomeIcon
    className="fa-1x"
    icon={
      val === 1 ? faDice1 :
        val === 2 ? faDice2 :
          val === 3 ? faDice3 :
            val === 4 ? faDice4 :
              val === 5 ? faDice5 :
                val === 6 ? faDice6 :
                  null}
  />;
```

Into roughly something like this: -

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid(`faDice${val}`)} />
```

I have slogged away at this, and I really should leave it, but it's a burning itch :)

EDIT: So, the installation instructions came from [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/). I also created these 2 config files in the root directory.

```
// Babel-plugin-macros.config.js
module.exports = {
    'fontawesome-svg-core': {
        'license': 'free'
    }
}
```

and

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function (api) {
    return {
        plugins: ['macros'],
    }
}
```

I did try the code

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-dice-one" />
```

However, it didn't render to the svg that the following line game me.

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon=faDiceOne />
```

Comment: I ran this and it worked.    ->    npm install babel-plugin-macros

Answer (score 1):

### Context

I reproduced this issue in this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-phoebe-nts66c?file=/src/App.js)

I got this error.

> /src/App.js: @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro: config license must be either 'free' or 'pro' Learn more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core

The error has something to do with `free` or `pro` plan. We are using a free plan and as I can see, you are following a tutorial; it might also be a free plan. (Instructos online use `free` versions in the course )

We have the right access to solid() function, but the solid function is not present in the module.

To put it straight the solid function definition (typescript definition) is exported but the function is not (mostly because this function has been removed in the latest versions ).

See the official source code.
Type exported in the [file import.macro.d.ts](https://github.dev/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/d3a7818c253fcbafff9ebd1d4abb2866c192e1d7/js-packages/%40fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro.d.ts#L18)
But solid function is missing in the module. (Check the explorer on the left side )

To support this. There is a comment in the code saying

> // The macros corresonding to legacy style names: solid(), regular(), light(), thin(), duotone(), brands().

Check this in the official source code [import.macro.js](https://github.dev/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/d3a7818c253fcbafff9ebd1d4abb2866c192e1d7/js-packages/%40fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro.js#L78)

The above issue could have occurred due to the difference in Fontawesome versions between you and the instructor ( This is a common issue as videos can't be re-recorded every new version released.)

### Solution here

This is how you can implement a dice in Font-Awesome React

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-dice-one" />
```

For passing icon as a variable you can do something like this

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon=`fa-solid fa-dice-${val}` />
```

Answer (score 0):

Run npm install --save @babel/helper-module-imports

This is works for me..